# How to import a object of another model (A) inside model (B) in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a new object in `ModelB` when specific condition are met in `ModelA`. I am new to Django so that I am unable to figure out how exactly I can achieve this.

For example I have two models(`Product` and `ProductVariant`), when specific condition on `ProductVariant` is met then I want to calculate new object value in `Product` model.

My `Product` model is like this:

```
PRODUCT_TYPE = (
    ('s', 'simple'),
    ('v', 'varaible')
)

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True, blank=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,null=True)
    short_description = HTMLField()
    description = HTMLField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name="products",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True,)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brands,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True,)
    warranty_support = HTMLField()
    product_type = models.CharField(choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, default='simple', max_length=50)
```

And my Product Attribute Model is like this:

```
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, default=None)
    managed_stock = models.IntegerField(choices=STOCK_MANAGED, default=0)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    stock_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length= 250, default=None)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sale_start_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, default=None)
    sale_end_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False,default=None)
```

I am trying to create `regular_price` and `sale_price` on `Product` model if `product_type` is variable and if `sale_end_date` is greater than today. I want to set the `price` from the `variant` which has the lowest price.

I tried doing like this on `Product` model:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.product_type == 'varaible' and ProductVariant.objects.filter(product=self, variant_count__gt = 1):           
        self.min_price = ProductVariant.objects.filter(product=self).Min('price')
        self.max_price = ProductVariant.objects.filter(product=self).Max('price')
```

but I am not able to achieve what I want,
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and analysis I found solution to my problem, I am posting the solution here so that someone with similar problem could be benefited.

```
@property
    def get_price(self):
        result = dict()
        variants = ProductVariant.objects.filter(product=self)
        count = variants.count()
        if count > 1:
            min_variant = variants.order_by('price').first()
            max_variant = variants.order_by('-price').first()
            result['min_price'] = min_variant.price
            result['max_price'] = max_variant.price

        elif count == 1:
            variant = variants.first()
            if variant.sale_price:
                result['price'] = variant.price
                result['sale_price'] = variant.sale_price
                sale_variant = variants.order_by('sale_price').first()
                result['lowest_sale_price'] = sale_variant.sale_price
                result['regular_price'] = sale_variant.price
                today = datetime.date.today()
                if variant.sale_start_date <= today and variant.sale_end_date >= today:
                    result['sale_end_date'] = variant.sale_end_date
            else:
                result['price'] = variant.price
```